# return specific index of array using val() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I may lack basic knowledge of retrieving data in Javascript. So I am reading the value of range slider using a jquery plugin called noUiSlider. Here is there basic code:

html:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="value-input-left" style="font-size:12px"></div>
<div id="value-input-right" style="font-size:12px"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#slider").noUiSlider({
       start: [20, 80],
       connect: true,
       range: {
       'min': 0,
       'max': 100
        }
     });
      $('#slider').Link('lower').to($('#value-input-left'));
      $('#slider').Link('upper').to($('#value-input-right'));
      alert("return value of range slider" +$("#slider").val());
      });

</script>
```

The `$("#slider").val()` returns  `array[value, value]`, in this example it's 20.00, 80.00. But what is the easiest way to get their value separately?

For instance, I've tried:`$("#slider").val(0)`;  `$("#slider").val[0]` , `$("#slider").lower()` and `$("#slider").get(0)` but none of them works.

The documentation of this plugin is http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#slider").val()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val() is still what you want, but since it's returning an array, you have to use your accessor on val(). Putting them both together:

```
$("#slider").val()[0] // first value
$("#slider").val()[1] // second value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#slider").val()[0];
```

To get the first element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If its everything like you tell, try the following:

```
$("#slider").val()[0];
```